# Count across multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

I want to find in `Dx1, Dx2, Dx3` add the number of times the same category and group repeats the name of the category.

**Table Categories:**

```
ID Name
1   A
2   B
```

**Table Dx:**

```
ID   Dx 1   Dx 2    Dx 3
1    1       1       1
2    1       1       2
```

**Result query:**

```
Category_name Count_dx*
A               5
B               1
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It Would Be Better. If You Show Your *Tried Query*

Comment: you are welcome to stack overflow. Please, edit your question showing us what you have tried so far and where do you get stuck at. This is not a "write code on demand site". Take the few minutes [tour](http://stackoverflow/tour) to learn how this site works.

Comment: I want to get the sum of the values repeated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving the answer although your question seems implicit.

```
SELECT 
Categories.Name,
COUNT(*) AS Count_dx
FROM Categories
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    Dx1 dx_val
    FROM Dx

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
    Dx2 dx_val
    FROM Dx

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
    Dx3 dx_val
    FROM Dx
) AS t
ON Categories.ID = t.dx_val
GROUP BY t.dx_val;
```

Probably you want to get the **count of category IDs** (for each category) across the three columns (`Dx1, Dx2 and Dx3`) in `Dx table`. If so then the above query does the job.